# $.post AJAX request: How to check if returned value is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have an AJAX call using the $.post() method and wanted to know how I can check if the returned value is empty or not.

This is the code:

```
$.post(site_url, function(data) {
    if(!data) {
      alert('Nope');
    } else {
      alert('Yay');
    }
});
```

But this does not work. I also tried checking if the object is NULL or =="", but still no effect..

**EDIT**

data.length made the job! Thanks, guys

Comment: What makes you say that it is empty?

Comment: That depends on the data ur getting. but, most of time, checking for `null` or checking `length` will spill the beans

Comment: It's not a good practice to use empty string or null result of a request. You should always have a well defined result. For example in case of no result, you could have an empty array, then check for the length in JS.

Comment: .length made it! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$.post(site_url, function(data,status) {
    alert("Status="+status);
});
```

This will display the status of ajax request("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or "parsererror")

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
typeof(data.responseText) === null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $.post(site_url, function(data) {
        if(!empty(data)) {
        alert('Yay');  
        } else {
        alert('Nope');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

If the string comparison with ajax-response fails, then try sending numeric value in ajax-response and compare.

```
**demo.php**
<php
$temp = some_function();
//If the function returns null then send 1, else the value returned
if(temp!='')
   echo 1;
else
  echo $temp;
?>

$.post(demo.php, function(data) {
if (data != 1)
{
  alert('null');
}
else
{
  alert(data);
}
});
```